# How do you access the returned data from useMutation in react-apollo-hooks?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-hooks

I currently have the mutation hook set up as following:

```
const bookItem = useMutation(CREATE_BOOKING_MUTATION, { 
    variables: mutationVariables,
    refetchQueries: [{ query: getPosts }]
})
```

The `refetchQueries` property is set in place, but console.logging `bookItem` does not give me access to the returned data.

Edit:
@xadm

I wanted to access the retrieved data from the delete mutation as well using the `update` property as you mentioned, but still had difficulty accessing the returned info.

```
const onDeleteHandler = useMutation(DELETE_POST, {
        update: (proxy, mutationResult) => {
            try {
                const { deletePost } = mutationResult.data;
                const postFeed = proxy.readQuery({
                    query: GET_POSTS, variables
                })
                const data = _.omit(postFeed, [deletePost.id])
                proxy.writeQuery({ query: GET_POSTS, variables, data })
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log("Cache update error", error)
            }
          },
        })
```

Comment: The `useMutation` is documented to return a mutation function.

You only have access to data is a query or subscription when using `react-apollo-hooks`

Comment: `update` option is the place where you can access mutation results

Comment: I tried using it with `update` but still face the question of how to access the retrieved data.  I updated my question to include the example